# Нужно ли избегать двух тире? Если да, то как?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Растём ли мы по жизни, стоим на месте или деградируем — во многом это определяет одна вещь — наше окружение.*

Является ли нежелательным постановка двух тире в предложении? Я читал, что в случае двух двоеточий одно из них заменяют на тире, где это уместно. Какая практика при скоплении тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Растём ли мы по жизни, стоим на месте или деградируем, — во многом это определяет одна вещь — наше окружение.**

1) Нежелательно (даже при авторском употреблении) повторение знака тире, когда знаки ставятся на разном основании: [Взаимодействие знаков препинания в сложных конструкциях. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации онлайн. Полный академический справочник Лопатина.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)

2) Поэтому ставим запятую и тире как единый знак.

Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении: [Пунктуация. § 40. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении. Розенталь: Справочник по русскому языку](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)

1) перед главной частью, которой предшествует **ряд однородных придаточных**, если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на две части (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза): Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем (Добр.);

Comment: Но здесь же у нас не однородные придаточные, а однородные члены: растём, стоим на месте и деградируем, а у Розенталя такого случая нет.

Comment: Однородные сказуемые можно рассматривать как неполные предложения: Растём ли мы по жизни, стоим (ли мы) на месте... И главное - общий принцип один и тот же. Невозможно (даже Розенталю) прорешать все возможные задачи, что-то надо и самим думать.  У Вас есть другие предложения? Переделывать предложение, если не умеем расставить знаки? Поставить двоеточие? Но интонационно там именно тире (без увеличенной паузы).

Comment: Мне просто было необходимо пояснение. Вы его дали (про неполные предложения). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Поставивший два тире обрекает читателя на поиски вставки. Поскольку здесь она отсутствует, то для облегчения понимания с первого прочтения проще всего второе тире заменить на двоеточие. Основание для этого есть: далее раскрывается "одна вещь".

Answer (score 1):

> Растём ли мы по жизни, стоим на месте или деградируем — во многом это
>   определяет одна вещь — наше окружение.

Фразу лучше переделать - любым способом, чтобы эти два тире исключить.
Идея воспользоваться запятой с тире как единым знаком тут не спасает. Мало того, что основания для такого подхода сомнительны (у Розенталя перечислены все случаи, нашего там нет), так еще просто не избавляет от проблем восприятия, из-за которых, собственно, и придумана рекомендация избавляться от двух тире..

Причины рекомендации избегать двух тире чисто практические: при двух тире обычно теряется наглядность фразы, и то, что первое тире поставлено как единый знак совершенно не спасает.

> Является ли нежелательным постановка двух тире в предложении?

По ситуации. В тех редких случаях, когда два тире разнесены на значительное расстояния и не мешают восприятию синтаксиса, такое возможно.

> Какая практика при скоплении тире?

Ну это смотря что считать "скоплением"... Но в целом - да, обычно редакторы правят. Если ничего не изменилось за последние лет пятнадцать - я давно напрямую не сталкивался.

> Я читал, что в случае двух двоеточий одно из них заменяют на тире, где это уместно.

Да, такая рекомендация есть. Но её тоже нельзя считать ни общепризнанной, ни универсальной. В любом случае это отдельный случай, там причины несколько другие.